# cat command not displaying file contents with begin with + sign

Tags: shell

I have created a file with contents as given below.

> +---------------------------+
>   | Tasks                     
>   +---------------------------+
>   | 1) option one      
>   | 2) option two                  
>   +---------------------------+

But it is not displaying anything while I am trying to run the following command

> cat < filename

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What *does* happen when you type that command?  Are there any errors or other output?  Can you post the output of `ls -l filename` followed immediately by `cat filename`?

Comment: Nothing, not even an error message displayed while `cat filename`.I had made the permission to 777 after creating the file.Initially the permission was -rw-r--r-- .

Comment: ... and the output of `ls -l filename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cat filename`. The redirection isn't necessary.

(You could do `cat - < filename` also).

Comment: It's not necessary, but it ought to work.  `cat < filename` and `cat - < filename` are identical in behavior. The `-` argument is typically only used if you're trying to concatenate multiple files along with `stdin` (e.g., `cat file1 - file2`).

Comment: @larsks I just about to ask, then why cat< foo didn't work... :)

Comment: larsks, true. It shouldn't matter. (It does seem silly to do a redirection, though). I guess the answer then is either "your system is broken" or "the file doesn't contain what you think it contains".

Comment: user103134, how about just `cat filename`?

Comment: When I tried `echo \`cat < filename\`` , it showed the first line only. `+----------------+`

Comment: again, how about just `cat filename`?

Comment: I don't know what happened with the former file.I just copied the whole content to a new file and it just worked fine with `cat - < testfile`.

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 59 Mar  8 10:41 testfile

Comment: Thank you all for your support and help :)